# Does raw_spin_lock in Linux disable hrtimer interrupts?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, deadlock, spinlock

On one processor, in the same thread, first raw_spin_lock() is called, then it starts a hrtimer and goes back to  raw_spin_lock() again where it will spin there. In the hrtimer interrupt handler function, raw_spin_unlock() will be called.

Will this cause a deadlock or not? Will spinning on  raw_spin_lock() disable interrupt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raw_spin_lock_irq()` and `raw_spin_lock_irqsave()` disable local interrupts, however interrupts on other CPUs still may occur. `raw_spin_lock()` does not.

Using spin locks with local interrupts enabled carelessly may lead to a deadlock if any interrupt handler attempts to lock already held spin lock. For the same reason none of the functions I mentioned is re-entrant. It will not be possible for the lock owner to ever release the lock. However, since in this case ISR will release the lock deadlock should not be a problem.

I think you should also check out *completion variables* which were designed to do what you seem to try to accomplish using spin lock in such unusual way. See [this](http://www.makelinux.com/books/lkd2/ch09lev1sec7) and also functions `wait_on_completion(_interruptible)(_timeout)()` [here](http://kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers.html).

More information on spin locks can be found [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/spinlocks.txt?v=3.6).

Comment: Dziepak  Understand, but in my situation, my interrupt handler only unlocks not locks. I hope this is fine?

Comment: I have noticed a problem. The same thread tries to call raw_spin_lock() for the second time before the spinlock is unlocked once. Maybe this will cause problem.